# How do I set my Ethminer adress?

Tags: mining, ethminer

How do I set the address that mining rewards are sent? This means that ethminer will send mining rewards to that a address.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you have ethminer installed.... you need to also be running your own node. The miner will not run without a node to run on top of. You can use geth or parity both are pretty popular.

in parity: 
`parity --author <YOUR ADDRESS HERE>`

in geth: 
`geth --mine --etherbase <YOUR ADDRESS HERE>`